# How to execute a file that requires being in the same directory?

Tags: python

I have a python script that needs to execute a `.jar` file that is located in another directory. What would be the best way to do this? So far I was thinking -

```
subprocess.call(["cd","/path/to/file"])
subprocess.call(["./file.jar"])
```

How should I do this?

**Update:**

Using both of the answers below, this is what I ended up doing:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split("./file.jar -rest -of -command"), cwd=COMMAND_FOLDER)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run a process in a different current working directory, use `subprocess.Popen`'s `cwd` parameter:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['file.jar'], cwd = '/path/to/file')
```

Answer (score 2):

howabout using:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = "the command to use to execute your binary"


args = shlex.split(cmd)
try:
    p = subprocess.call(args)
except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
```